# позиционирование элементов на бутстрап

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Встрял на позиционировании элементов в блоке. Как лучше обработать? Должно быть вот так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.info__per {
    width: 310px;

}

.line__two {
    position: absolute;
    width: 292px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #555555;
    opacity: 0.2;
    left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="about__person">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <p class="author">Author</p>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <img src="https://www.mastersecrets.ru/media/cache/universal/rc/LCdlGBCm/uploads/2017/01/15/9cacb93ccca1ac1cd3837e31d8197c14.jpeg" alt="">
      <div class="info__per">
        <h2>Karen Grey</h2>
        <p class="place">United States</p>
        <div class="social d-flex">
          <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
          <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
          <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
          <i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="line__two"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как например:

```css
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.author-photo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius:50%;
  
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.author-photo img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.author-name {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.author-adress {
  font-weight: light;
}

.author-social a {
  color:#ccc;
}

.author-wrap hr {
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.author-signature {
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="author-wrap pt-2 mr-md-4">   
  
        <h4 class="px-4"><i>Author</i></h4>
        <hr>

        <div class="author-box py-4">
          <div class="d-sm-flex ">
            <div class="author-photo ">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502323777036-f29e3972d82f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=762ab46fb81f4b88e628a11024a32330&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="author-content px-sm-4">
              <div class="author-top mb-4">
                <h3 class="author-name">
                  Karen Gray
                </h3>

                <div class="author-adress">
                  Unated States
                </div>

                <ul class="list-inline author-social my-2">
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>

                <hr>
              </div>

              <div class="author-body">
                <h4><i>About Lemon</i></h4>

                <div class="author-text">
                  <p>
                    <i>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo quibusdam reiciendis, ea alias unde, repudiandae doloremque eaque deleniti natus velit.
                    </i>
                  </p>
                </div>

                <div class="author-signature pull-right">
                  <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/laracroft/images/e/ea/Signature.png/revision/latest?cb=20110528173852" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться стилями [медиа-объектов](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#media) в бутстрапе, а также классами для [изображений](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#images-shapes)

```css
.info__per {
    width: 310px;

}

.line__two {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    width: 292px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #555555;
    opacity: 0.2;
    left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object img-circle" src="https://www.mastersecrets.ru/media/cache/universal/rc/LCdlGBCm/uploads/2017/01/15/9cacb93ccca1ac1cd3837e31d8197c14.jpeg" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="info__per">
        <h2>Karen Grey</h2>
        <p class="place">United States</p>
        <div class="social d-flex">
          <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
          <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
          <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
          <i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="line__two"></div>
      </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```